# Questions about the current state of a tv series

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen a couple of these now, and I'm just not sure about them.  These questions ask if a tv series has been cancelled.  These essentially boil down to a yes or no answer.  I don't see the value in them.  They aren't a common question though so....

Thoughts?  Am I being picky?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a blatant yes or no, then ***nuke it from orbit.***

If they are asking "What production decisions caused *Unicorns in Space* to be cancelled?", its a definite maybe.  They would have to make it clear that their intention is to gain an understanding of *Why is this?* not *Is it?*.

Comment: +1 for *why* > *is*

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes production teams doesn't clarifies the status of TV series/upcoming shows and all. And media came up with so many unproved rumors.  So in that state this type of question got rise up.

I have also asked that similar kind of question [what-happend-to-the-reality-show-veena-ka-swayamvar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/what-happend-to-the-reality-show-veena-ka-swayamvar).

I don't think that these type of question are not useful but in my opinion  this kind of question are very useful not for a single person but for more.

Comment: The issue is that those kinds of questions are closer to news or speculation than anything else. Ask yourself: will this question be useful in 5 years? While there may be some people interested in the answer *now*, questions about the current production status of a show by definition will be less useful in the future (because we will eventually know whether or not they're filming again).

Comment: @stevvve their are so many other kind of question too which are not useful in future such as identify-this-movie and question about future coming movie.Is that we are only want question which will help in future? or we want question which help people in present time? or both?

Comment: I certainly agree regarding the questions about the future release of a movie (depending on how they're phrased). Identify-this-movie questions are dubious in their own right, but if they are done well can absolutely be useful to others as there may be people with searching for that movie in the future. Think about it this way: 'current production' questions have a limited period of utility, as in they will cease to be informative because the info they provide expires. Identify-this questions could be useful *forever*.

Comment: i think thinking of helpful question for future will only neglect the present question's which are very useful too